# openssl in C# to match openssl des-ede3-cbc in linux

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio-2008, cryptography, openssl

I need to encrypt the data in linux and decrypt this data in windows C# application.
I am encrypted using following command in linux.
openssl enc -des-ede3-cbc -K 3B388F0EFDA72AF16DBA734FE9704AF7 -iv 0000000000000000  -in file.txt -out file.enc.
If try to decrypt in C# application using DLL provided in http://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl-net/. I am not able to get proper decrypted data. Please send me equivalent C# code to decrypt in windows.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [MSDN examples for TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and do not forget to set correct Mode, Key, IV and Padding properties of your instance:

```
var provider = new System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
provider.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
provider.Key = new byte[] { 0x3B, 0x38, 0x8F, 0x0E, 0xFD, 0xA7, 0x2A, 0xF1, 0x6D, 0xBA, 0x73, 0x4F, 0xE9, 0x70, 0x4A, 0xF7, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
provider.IV = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
provider.Padding = System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.PKCS7;
```

You should also add -p option to your command so you can see the actual key used by OpenSSL for encryption:

```
$ openssl enc -des-ede3-cbc -K 3B388F0EFDA72AF16DBA734FE9704AF7 -iv 0000000000000000 -in file.txt -out file.enc -nosalt -p
key=3B388F0EFDA72AF16DBA734FE9704AF70000000000000000
iv =0000000000000000
```

The key you are passing on the command line is too short so OpenSSL appends zeros to it and you need to use exactly the same key in your C# code.

Comment: byte[] encdata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\encrypt.txt");
ICryptoTransform ct = provider.CreateDecryptor();
byte[] output = ct.TransformFinalBlock(encdata, 0, encdata.Length);
provider.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("decrpted --->" + System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(output));
System.Console.ReadKey();  This is my application in C#. I am getting "Bad data" exception for "TransformFinalBlock". Please help me to solve this.

Comment: It is not working. First I am encrypting in linux PC and copying encrypted file to windows PC. Then running C# application to decrypt the file data. I am getting error "A cryptographic error occured : Bad data". How can fix this?

Comment: @user3020723 I have tested it in exactly the same scenario - encrypted on Linux with OpenSSL and decrypted on Windows with C# application - and I can confirm it is working. Did you append 8 zeros to the key value?

Comment: I am setting proper mode. i.e cbc.

Comment: @user3020723 Have you read my updated answer? Have you updated your provider.Key value?

Comment: No  jariq. I have not appended 8 zeros to the key value. If you have the C# working code, can you please share it to me? I need to resolve it ASAP.